# PHP server side timer?

Tags: php, timer

I want to create a single timer that is displayed on my site, I want for it to be synchronous across all clients trying to access it.  When a client clicks the "increase" button, I want the timer to add 1 minute to the countdown and I want this change to be reflected for all clients.

Is this achievable through PHP?  Any tips/advice to get me started?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a click from any client to effect all clients you will need to base the solution either on Polling (refreshing an AJAX hit) or [Comet programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). A comet programming solution is more complex, but allow you to push the timer updates to all the clients in *real time*.

Word of Advice:
Unless your website is planning on doing a large amount of asynchronous communication, I'd just stick with a simple polling solution. You could even have the AJAX poll a static file and update the static file via PHP (this updating needs to be done atomically). This means each AJAX poll will be *very* cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, but you need some delayed AJAX, the same technology used to created javascript chat windows, realtime logging etc.